# Clay strips intensity not working with symmetry

Tags: sculpting

I have a problem with clay strips tool when symmetry modifier is enabled - intensity is different on the other side of the symmetry. Problem becomes more apparent the lower the intensity is.

On the attached screenshot I made a couple of strokes with clay strips and as you can see the intensity differs. Some of the strokes cannot even be visible on the other side.

I've already tried playing with different settings, but maybe I am missing some particular setting. I've also tried googling but nobody apparently run into this issue before, so I am suspecting that the problem is in my geometry.

I'd appreciate some help on this, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem - the solution was to use the *Symmetrize* tool in Edit Mode:

[image]